# ssl_client_certificate failed 403 forbidden

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I was trying to install my organization client certificate chain (Pair of this certificate is installed on all organization user laptops so only organization users can access the service) in an ingress. I have created a secret with the below command

```
kubectl create secret generic auth-tls-chain --from-file=org_client_chain.pem --namespace=default
secret/auth-tls-chain created
```

And created my ingress as follows

```
metadata:
  name: my-new-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "default/auth-tls-chain"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "3"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-one
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: echo-tls
```

But when I try to access my domain am getting a "403 Forbidden" error. I opened nginx config file and can see the certificate has some issues

```
kubectl exec ingress-nginx-controller-5fbf49f7d7-sjvpw cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    # error obtaining certificate: local SSL certificate default/auth-tls-chain was not found
        return 403;
```

My client certificate chain looks like the one below in .PEM format.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
sdfkhdskhflds
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
saflsafhl
sfadfasdf
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

1. I tried creating the secret with the following command.

   kubectl create secret generic ca-secret --from-file=org_client_chain.pem=org_client_chain.pem

but no luck. Can somebody help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the Github [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#client-certificate-authentication) you must use the certificate file name as   ca.crt containing the full Certificate Authority chain.